# SQL Server count() returns different results when using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and I am not looking for a solution (but it may help others), rather, I would like to understand the behaviour / why I get two different results from the two pseudo queries below.

The reason I have joined two other tables is because I will need to count all items in Vehicle against the 'Date_Recorded' in 'Garage'. All recorded since 2010. So before I did this I wanted to be sure I was getting the same total count from the table 'Car' and also get the same result with the joins, before I added the 'isDate' on 'Garage' condition, that is when I noticed the difference in the results.

I would have thought the joins would have been ignored?

Hope someone can advise? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT count(Car.CAR_ID) AS Car_ID
FROM Vehicle Car
INNER JOIN Road Rd
ON Car.CAR_ID = Rd.CAR_ID
JOIN Garage g
ON Rd.GARAGE_ID = g.GARAGE_ID
----------------------------------------------
Car_ID
----------------------------------------------
226923


SELECT count(Car.CAR_ID) AS Car_ID
FROM Vehicle Car
----------------------------------------------
Car_ID
----------------------------------------------
203417
```

Comment: FYI - I don't think it matters in regards to your question, but in your query, INNER JOIN and JOIN do the same thing in SQL Server.

Comment: have a look if the columns `Rd.CAR_ID` and `g.GARAGE_ID`are primary keys in their tables. if not, there are maybe several roads per car or several garage per car

Comment: @Aツ thanks - yes they are all Primary Keys!

Comment: Huh? Road.Car_ID is a primary key?

Comment: are this single column prim keys or multiple columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables.
>
> LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table.
>
> RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table.
>
> FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables.

you are using inner join thats why you are getting the wrong result from the actual `count()` result.
if you want to get all the record from the left table the you have to use `left join` in this query then you'll get the result of `count()` same as the main table`[left table]`.

Comment: Thanks! - This also happens if I remove INNER and just leave JOIN

Comment: Thanks everyone I will go back and take a look at my Joins!

Answer (score 1):

You either have

- multiple records in the Road table with the same Car_ID or
- multiple records in the Road table with the same Garage_ID or
- Both of the above

You may be able to run the following to get what you want (assuming there is always a match in the road and garage tables):

```
 SELECT count(Distinct Car.CAR_ID) AS Car_ID
 FROM Vehicle Car
 INNER JOIN Road Rd
 ON Car.CAR_ID = Rd.CAR_ID
 JOIN Garage g
 ON Rd.GARAGE_ID = g.GARAGE_ID
```

Comment: and you've got 203417?